# Fastest way to update table nulls in postgresql from dataframe

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a pandas dataframe and matching postgresql table, where every cell in both is either null or a timestamp.
For each cell in the table where the cell value equals null, and the corresponding dataframe cell value is a timestamp, I want to update the table cell value. What's the fastest way to do this?

Currently I'm pulling in the whole table into a dataframe, comparing the two dataframes in python (cell by cell), entering those values into a 3rd dataframe (call it DFC), and then destroying the old table and building a new table from DFC. This seems inefficient.

Example:

```
**Data Frame**   **Postgres Table**
     A    B           A    B
1   NaN   5      1   NaN  NaN
2    8   NaN     2    7   NaN



**Goal State Postgres Table**
     A    B
1   NaN   5
2    7   NaN
```

Current Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

d = {'A': ['None', 8], 'B': [5, 'None']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
out = {'A': ['None', 'None'], 'B': ['None', 'None']}
outdf = pd.DataFrame(data=out)
tbl = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "exampletable"',con=engine)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for j in ['A', 'B']:
        if df.at[i, j] != 'None' and tbl.at[i, j] == 'None':
            outdf.at[i, j] = df.at[i, j]
        else:
            outdf.at[i, j] = tbl.at[i, j]
df.to_sql('exampletable', engine, if_exists='replace')
print(outdf.to_string())
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Figured that was superfluous since I showed the example and description, but I can also show my current process in code! One moment

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can merge the two databases but maintain a record of what records come from each. Then you can check if your A column is empty and fill in the B column with the B from df2.

```
outdf = df1.join(df2, on=columns, how="outer", rsuffix='_df2', lsuffix='_df1')
outdf['B'] = outdf.apply(lambda x: x['B_df2'] if pd.isnull(x['A']), axis=1)
```

**Edit**: you'd want to filter back down to different rows.

```
outdf = outdf.loc[:, [columns with _df1 suffix]]
outdf.columns = [i.replace('_df1', '') for i in columns]
outdf = outdf.sort_values(by='B')
outdf = outdf.drop_duplicates([columns you're not filling in], keep='first')
```

Comment: I get syntax errors for a few parts of this. I'm also not seeing "to_psql_df" as a command in pandas

Comment: Sorry, that was leftover from a longer version of the same answer. I've edited so it should work now. Also, if you know they're the same record due to the index, you can just leave out the `on` argument in the join.

Comment: thank you, but my example was a trimmed down version. In actuality, I have much more than 2 rows and 2 columns. I need to check every column for it's matching cell in the other dataframe

Comment: @singmotor So you'd have another _n_ number of A/B columns?  If that's the case, you can extract the second line of my first section into a function that checks whether a _x_ column is null and fills it in with _y_ column's value.

Comment: I have n columns a-z, and m rows 1-n.